# Convert GMM-UBM scores to equicalent accuracy percent

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, biometrics

I have constructed a GMM-UBM model for the speaker recognition purpose. The output of models adapted for each speaker some scores calculated by log likelihood ratio. Now I want to convert these likelihood scores to equivalent number between 0 and 100. Can anybody guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward formula. You can do simple things like

```
prob = exp(logratio_score)
```

but those might not reflect the true distribution of your data. The computed probability percentage of your samples will not be uniformly distributed.

Ideally you need to take a large dataset and collect statistics on what acceptance/rejection rate do you have for what score. Then once you build a histogram you can normalize the score difference by that spectrogram to make sure that 30% of your subjects are accepted if you see the certain score difference. That normalization will allow you to create uniformly distributed probability percentages. See for example [How to calculate the confidence intervals for likelihood ratios from a 2x2 table in the presence of cells with zeroes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61349/how-to-calculate-the-confidence-intervals-for-likelihood-ratios-from-a-2x2-table)

This problem is rarely solved in speaker identification systems because confidence intervals is not what you want actually want to display. You need a simple accept/reject decision and for that you need to know the amount of false rejects and accept rate. So it is enough to find just a threshold, not build the whole distribution.

Comment: I have used the sigmoid function for this problem but as you know it does not reflect scores distribution.  I intended to use the second way. Thank you for your good suggestion.