# Gaussian Mixture Model gives negative value scores

Tags: python, gmm

I am trying to train multiple GMM model with different training words. Then I am trying to test my models with an unseen testing word, I am getting negative values. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
from python_speech_features import delta
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture 
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import os, glob
import numpy as np
```

Reading all training files

```
rate = []#reading rates and signals of all Training wav files
sig = []
for filename in glob.glob('Data\Training\*.wav'):
    sr_value, x_value = wav.read(filename)
    rate.append(sr_value)
    sig.append(x_value)
```

Calculating mfcc for each signal

```
all_mfcc_feat = []
for audio in sig:
    #defaults
    all_mfcc_feat.append(mfcc(signal = audio, samplerate = 16000, winlen = 0.025, winstep = 0.01, nfilt=26, nfft = 512, numcep = 13, preemph = 0.97, ceplifter=22, appendEnergy =False))
```

Calculating deltas for each signal

```
delta_oneT = []
double_deltaT = []
for mfcc in all_mfcc_feat:
    delta1 = (delta(mfcc, 2))
    delta_oneT.append(delta1) #calculating delta
    double_deltaT.append(delta(delta1, 2)) #calculating double delta from previous delta

training_feat = []
for i in range (0, len(all_mfcc_feat)): #iterate through signals
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = None, )

    for j in range (0, len(all_mfcc_feat[i])): #iterate through list of mfcc's
        combined = np.concatenate([all_mfcc_feat[i][j],delta_oneT[i][j], double_deltaT[i][j] ])
        df = df.append(pd.Series(combined), ignore_index = True)
    dfnew = df.values
    training_feat.append(dfnew)


(sr_valueX, x_valueX) = wav.read('Data\Testing\wiehedT.wav')

mfcc_test = mfcc(x_valueX, sr_valueX)

delta_oneTest = []
double_deltaTest = []
delta1T = delta(mfcc_test, 2)
delta_oneTest.append(delta1T) #calculating delta
double_deltaTest.append(delta(delta1, 2)) #calculating double delta from previous delta


df = pd.DataFrame(data = None, )
for i in range (0, len(mfcc_test)):  
    combined = np.concatenate([mfcc_test[i],delta_oneTest[0][i],double_deltaTest[0][i]])
    df = df.append(pd.Series(combined), ignore_index = True) 
testingFeat = df.values

allmodels = []
for feat in training_feat:
    gmm = GaussianMixture() #default weights and means
    gmm.fit(feat)
    allmodels.append(gmm)

i = 1
for gmm in allmodels:
    print 'Model ',i
    scores = gmm.score(testingFeat)
    print scores
    i = i+1
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: what do you mean by that? plotted?

Comment: Grammar. // https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18967362

Answer (score 1):

The code works as expected. The function `gmm.score(testingFeat)` returns the computed log probabilities of each point in the input data. Here is [the documentation of score()](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM.score)

Log probabilities are simply the logarithm of the probabilities -which belong to the interval (0,1)- and so they are negative. To reverse this you can apply the exponential function as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465737/how-to-convert-log-probability-into-simple-probability-between-0-and-1-values-us).

However this won't result in percentage/probabilities like scores because your data might not be uniformly distributed. This is explained in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962585/convert-gmm-ubm-scores-to-equicalent-accuracy-percent).